# is design compiler& encounter is for ASIC design and quartus&modelsim is for FPGA design?

Tags: fpga, asic

Right now, I am trying on place-routing on encounter, but when I search on web, I always see the tuition about quartus routing. For curious, I try to find out the difference between two of them. However, there is not any exact answer right now. But when I moving the layout of these two tools made, I feel like quartus' layout is look like making on a settle down chip. But encounter would give me more customly feeling. Thus, I suppose quartus for FPGA encounter for ASIC. Am I right? If not, plz tell me the exact story.

Comment: Maybe you could rephrase your question so it's more of a question?

Answer (score 0):

Encounter is a place and route tool for custom silicon, so it can pick any cell from a library, put it anywhere within a placement block, and route metal to it on any available layer as needed.  The output of Encounter is a GDSII file showing what polygons need to be created on each layer as part of the silicon manufacturing process.

An FPGA has already placed all of the available transistors and wires within the device.  Quartus (or ISE, for Xilinx) maps logic into LUTs (the logic unit within an FPGA) and figures out how to connect the LUTs using available tracks between the logic blocks.  The output of Quartus is a bit stream which tells what values to put in to each LUT on the device and which routing tracks to select/connect between the LUTs.